# Limit and grouping stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an entity:

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int amount;
    private String description;
    private LocalDate reportDay;

//getters and setters with constructors
    
}
```

Everyday I want to get information about my `Items` for last 3 days (in report view). I have repository:

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT item from Item item where item.reportDate >= :daysAgoDate order by item.reportDate desc")
    List<Item> findAllWithDateAfter(@Param("daysAgoDate") LocalDate daysAgoDate);

}
```

And service for this:

```
@Service
public class ItemService {

    private final ItemRepository itemRepository;

    public List<Item> getItemsForRequiredDays(int days) {
        LocalDate daysAgoDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days);
        return itemRepository.findAllWithDateAfter(daysAgoDate);
    }
}
```

It works okay. But now I want to **limit** extracted rows. If I'll get more than 20 `items` from my query, I want to limit and group it by days. So I want to get **only 20 rows** (limit), and **only 10 rows for per day** (groupingby)

My method should looks like:

```
 public List<Item> getItemsForRequiredDays(int days) {
        LocalDate daysAgoDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(days);
        List<items> items = itemRepository.findAllWithDateAfter(daysAgoDate);
        int size = items.size();
        if (size > 20) {
            return items.stream()
                    .limit(20)
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getReportDate, //here i want to group by date -> only 10 rows for each day));
        }
        else {
            return items;
        }
    }
```

How to do this? I'm stuck with grouping.

Comment: Wouldn't it be really good to extract the data from your datastore rather than computing it on the application layer? Thinking of functional correctness as well.

Comment: Anyway I need to know, what was the real size of list with all rows.

Comment: Are the items guaranteed to be sorted? Or are you basically picking twenty random elements and *then*, group by date and limiting again to ten per day? That means, the result could be twenty items from twenty different days or just ten items from one day *for the same source data*.

Comment: All items are saved every day, and I've composite key including date. I'm picking not random elements, only elements for past three days. If there are more such elements, i want to get only 20 of them. And if it will return for example 15 rows for one day, 5 rows for second day, and 10 rows for third day,  i want to limit it to 10 elements max per day, to see not all elements for these days, but as many dates as possible.

Comment: Your items are sorted as 1st day items then 2nd day items, 3rd day items... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `ReportDate` then groupingBy `ReportDate`. Then flatten the item using `flatMap` limit on maximum 10 item perDay then limit 20 item only.

```
return items.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Item::getReportDate).reversed()) //If you need top 20 
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getReportDate,
                    LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .flatMap(items -> items.stream().limit(10))
        .limit(20)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking to:

```
return items.stream()
        .limit(20)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Item::getReportDay))
        .values().stream()
        .flatMap(items -> items.stream().limit(10))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will return a multiple rows with multiple dates, and each date can present at max 10 times.

Comment: Looks like what i need.

Comment: I think `.limit(20)` operation needs to do after flattening the items since if already 20 items selected of one day then it's gives wrong result.